# Converting a List into Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, datatable

Assume that I have a list like `PL = { P1, 0, 10, P2, 5, 20 }` and I need to convert it a datatable like

```
ProcessName  ArrivalTime  CpuTime
P1           0            10
P2           5            20
```

The number of process (row count) is dynamic. And I have tried sth like this:

```
protected DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    int j = 0;
    List<string> PL = CreateProcessList();
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < PL.Count - 2; i += 3)
    {
        DataRow ProcessRow = DT.NewRow();
        DT.Rows[j][0] = PL[i].ToString();
        DT.Rows[j][1] = Convert.ToInt32(PL[i + 1]);
        DT.Rows[j][2] = Convert.ToInt32(PL[i + 2]);
        j++;
    }
    DT.Columns.Add("Header", typeof(string));
    DT.Columns[0].ColumnName = "ProcessName";
    DT.Columns[1].ColumnName = "ArrivalTime";
    DT.Columns[2].ColumnName = "CpuTime";
    return DT;
}
```

It does not work (says that there is no row at position 0). Thanks for any idea.

#### Working Code After Editions:

```
    protected DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        List<string> PL = CreateProcessList();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT.Columns.Add("ProcessName", typeof(string));
        DT.Columns.Add("ArrivalTime", typeof(int));
        DT.Columns.Add("CpuTime", typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < PL.Count - 2; i += 3)
        {
            DataRow ProcessRow = DT.NewRow();
            ProcessRow[0] = PL[i].ToString();
            ProcessRow[1] = Convert.ToInt32(PL[i + 1]);
            ProcessRow[2] = Convert.ToInt32(PL[i + 2]);
            DT.Rows.Add(ProcessRow);
        }

        return DT;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second iteration of your `for` loop `i` is 3, so you're getting the 4th row of your table (at this point in time your table has 2 row).  You're then getting the 4th, 5th, and 6th columns of that row (your table has 0 columns, as you haven't added any columns yet) to set their value.  The corresponding index out of range errors should be telling you *exactly* what's wrong here.

Don't access the i-th row from the table.  Just use `ProcessRow` to access the row; it's right there in a variable for you.  Don't access the i-th column, access the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd (and add the columns *before* you try to populate them.

Comment: thanks for reply, i edited my code as above. still " there is no row at position 0".

Comment: @samet Then you *didn't* edit your code in all of the ways that I described that you should, namely you're still trying to access the row by its index.

Answer (score 1):

To create a datatable in the way you have described, you need to follow a different way.

1. Create a datatable object
2. Add [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the datatable object by using the [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method
3. use the datatable objects [NewRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get a [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object with the same schema as your datatable
4. populate the columns of this DataRow with the desired values
5. Add this DataRow to the Rows collection of your datatable object by using the [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method
6. repeat step 3 to 6 until your list reaches the end.

Comment: Thanks for this another exact solution!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Keep adding to curRow until the current iteration starts with 'P'. When it does start with 'P', add the currentRow to the data table and start a new row.

```
DataTable dataTable;
DataRow curRow;

... add columns to dataTable

for (var i = 0; i < PL.Count; i++) {
    if (PL[i].ToString().StartsWith("P")) {
        if (curRow != null)
            dataTable.Rows.Add(curRow);

        curRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    }

    ... add PL[i] to curRow
}
```

There's a few little issues with this but they can be fixed pretty easily. A check to make sure curRow is not null before adding to data table... that sorta thing.